# How to iterate through array just if the userinput is chronological in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I need a little bit of help please, I have the following code:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
String userinput= s.nextLine();
String[] books = new String[10];
books[0] = "book1”;
    books[1] = "book2";
if (Arrays.asList(userinput).contains(books[0])) {
    System.out.println("right, what is the next book?");
}
else {
    System.out.println("false");
}
```

My goal is to iterate through the array and ask the user the next input, so if he writes “book1”  I would like to automatically ask “what is the next book?” and I would wait for his answer to be “book2” and so on with book3,4,5.... in chronologic order. If he writes "book5" when I expect "book2", everything starts again until he gets it right, in chronological order

Comment: I think you should look at control loops to iterate over your array.  You probably would need an outer `while` loop to reset bad results and try again and an inner `for` loop to check the results.  If there is an error, `break` out of the `for` loop and try again.  You can also look at the methods contained in arrays and collections for ideas on sorting your list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for 3 books.

```
String[] books = new String[3];
books[0] = "book1";
books[1] = "book2";
books[2] = "book3";
boolean flag = true;
while(flag){ //outer loop 
    int counter = 0; //check for total right answers
    for(int i=0;i<books.length;i++){ //iterate over all books
        System.out.print("Choose book " + (i+1) +" name: ");
        String userinput= s.nextLine();

        if (Arrays.asList(userinput).contains(books[i])) {
            counter++;
            System.out.println("right, what is the next book?");


            if(counter == books.length){ //in case all choices are correct
                flag = false;
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Wrong");
            break;//terminate inner loop
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @EmanuelAlecsa if it's the right answer please answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to ensure that the books are entered in logical order in an array or list.  Then just compare `userInput` to the next entry.

```
        int nbooks = 5;  // number of books to generate
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        // create some books
        String[] books = IntStream.rangeClosed(1,nbooks)
               .mapToObj(i->"book"+i).toArray(String[]::new);

        int i = 0;
        String currentBook = books[i++];
        while (i < books.length) {
            System.out.println("The current book is " + currentBook);
            System.out.print("What is the next book? ");
            String userInput= s.next();
            if (userInput.equals(books[i++])) {
                if (i != books.length) {
                   // don't prompt at last book
                   System.out.println("right, what is the next book?");
                }
                continue;
            }
            // reset everything.
            System.out.println("False");
            i = 1;
            currentBook = books[0];
        }
        System.out.println("Congratulations! You got them all.");
```